# Is there a way to replace this loop to find Instr?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops

I have 'for i = 1 to x' loop to fill columns however it is very slow.
I don't have enough knowledge of vba to know a different way.

Here is my code:

```
Dim j As Long
j = 6

For i = 4 To EFlast_row
If InStr(ef.Cells(i, ActualTitleColumn).Value, search.Cells(searchboxrow, searchboxcolumn).Value)Then
    search.Cells(j, SearchLayerColumn).Value = ef.Cells(i, layercolumn).Value
    j = j + 1
End If
Next i
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Would be great to have an example that we would be able to replicate. Right now its anyones guess on your variables =)

Comment: You can use Autofilter and then loop through the filtered range?

Comment: Use a Range.Find, Range.FindNext loop to search and process relevant cells

Answer (score 0):

This code will put the data from sheets into a range variable. Comparisons using range variables are significantly quicker than using a reference like:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value
```

You will need to update this to reflect the variables you are using.

```
Function search()

' Put data on sheets into ranges
Dim rangeOne As Range, rangeTwo As Range
Set rangeOne = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
Set rangeTwo = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange

' Iterands for rangeOne and rangeTwo respectively
Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = 2 To rangeOne.Rows.Count
    For j = 2 To rangeTwo.Rows.Count

        If InStr(rangeOne(i, 1).Value2, rangeTwo(j, 1).Value2) Then

            rangeTwo(j, 2).Value2 = rangeOne(i, 2).Value2

        End If

    Next j
Next i

End Function
```